# How to make android app in java with counter automatically increment integer by 1 every 24 hours?

Tags: java, integer, counter

I want to make the app increase the integer by 1 every 24 hours, I have set a `sharedpreferences` to save the value in the app whenever it closes.

How can I get the app to calculate days passed whenever opened?

I also want the button to reset the counter.

**I have tried** searching google but I'm not finding a solution specific to my problem.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int days;
    Button bt;
    TextView textView;
    private SharedPreferences counter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        counter = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("shareware", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        days = counter.getInt("days",0);

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(days));
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                days++;
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(days));
                counter.edit().putInt("days", days).apply();
                Log.i("Test: ", Integer.toString(counter.getInt("days", days)));
                Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt);
                bt.setText("Reset");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do it the other around: store the time when the reset button was last pressed in shared preferences. Each time you open the app, calculate how many days have passed.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you're getting the time/date from the phone itself, then the user could probably change the date on the phone to fool your check.

Comment: Ok so I would use localdatetime funcions.